# Magento2.3.4 different hours in REST API call GET Orders and the real order hour timezone

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, date, time

I have selected Timezone (Configuration->General->Locale Options)

```
Central European Standard Time (Europe/Warsaw)
```

Order 10004 has been created at:

```
Sep 21, 2021, 5:59:34 PM
```

When I send API request:

```
https://www.mysite.pl/rest/V1/orders/89
```

I've got these result:

```
"created_at": "2021-09-21 15:59:34",
"entity_id": 89,
"increment_id": "10004",
```

My MYSQL request:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Is also correct:

```
+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |

+---------------------+

| 2021-09-21 16:05:05 |

+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My php.ini conf files are set to:

```
date.timezone = CET
```

Nginx status

```
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-07-20 17:17:49 CEST; 2 months 2 days ago
```

Ubuntu serwer date after command:

```
date
```

Output:

```
Wed Sep 22 12:22:57 CEST 2021
```

So everything dates matches except REST API requests.

So difference in time there is 2 hours. How it possible ? How Can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento stores dates/times in the database as UTC. "CEST" is Central European Summer Time which is UTC+2 so it looks like the times are correct. What you need to do with the API response is localise it to the desired timezone. Hope that helps.